# Why isn't my socket.on() autoscroll function working?

Tags: html, jquery, css, node.js

I'm trying to set up this auto-scroll function:

```
const autoscroll = () => {
// New message element
const $newMessage = $messages.lastElementChild

// Height of the new message
const newMessageStyles = getComputedStyle($newMessage)
const newMessageMargin = parseInt(newMessageStyles.marginBottom)
const newMessageHeight = $newMessage.offsetHeight + newMessageMargin

// Visible height
const visibleHeight = $messages.offsetHeight

// Height of messages container
const containerHeight = $messages.scrollHeight

// How far have I scrolled?
const scrollOffset = $messages.scrollTop + visibleHeight

if (containerHeight - newMessageHeight <= scrollOffset) {
    $messages.scrollTop = $messages.scrollHeight}
}
```

This is the socket.on() function. It works just fine up until the autoscroll():

```
socket.on('message', (message) => {
console.log(message)
let stamp = localized.format(Date.now());
const html = Mustache.render(messageTemplate, {
    username: message.username,
    message: message.text,
    createdAt: stamp
})
$messages.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
autoscroll()
})
```

When I inspect the site on my browser, there are no errors. The function runs, but the page position doesn't change. Should it be `autoscroll('message')` inside of the socket function? I can't figure out what the problem is.. here is the HTML.

```
    <script id="message-template" type="text/html">
            <div class="message">
                <p>
                    <span class="message__name">{{username}}</span>
                    <span class="message__meta" id="message-meta">{{createdAt}}</span>
                </p>
                <p id="message-text">{{message}}</p>
            </div>
        </script>
```

I've got socket.io, jQuery, mustache, moment, etc. all linked to the main HTML and everything works fine up until it's time to change the scroll position.

Comment: Maybe you want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView?

Comment: Tried ```const $messages = document.querySelector('#messages')
var lastChild = $messages.lastChild``` and replacing autoscroll() with lastChild.scrollIntoView and that doesn't work either..

Comment: Try playing around with it's options